# Angular : router naviagte comes before guard is complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

inside my **Angular 8** app , i ve this routing file :

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: FirstComponent , canActivate: [RegistrationSrcdGuard]},
  {path: 'FirstComponent ',
    component: FirstComponent ,
    canActivate: [myModuleGuard] ,
    children:[
      {path: 'SecondComponent ', component: SecondComponent , canActivate: [myModuleGuard]},
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(myRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

inside my FirstComponent.ts  , i ve this navigation action :

```
goToSecond(){
      this.router.navigate(['FirstComponent/SecondComponent '], {skipLocationChange: true});
}
```

My problem is that navigation seems to hang on , since , as i imagine , the treatment behind "**myModuleGuard**" takes a while ,

that's why , within an ugly workroud  , i ve changed it like the following :

```
goToSecond(){
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['FirstComponent/SecondComponent '], {skipLocationChange: true});
  });
}
```

And that makes it work , but , this seems to be rude . Especially the use of `setTimeout`

My Guard looks like this :

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
      canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const result = this.myService.getPermission();
        return result ;
      }

public getPermission() {
    let myResult : boolean
    myTreatment().subscribe(
      res => {
        return myResult = res;
      },
      err => {}
    );
    return myResult ;
  }
    }
```

**Your propositions to make it better ??**

Comment: Can you post the code for `myModuleGuard`

Comment: Why are you using a guard if you don't want to wait for the operation. This totally defies the logic of using canActivate.

Comment: @AkshayRana of course i want to wait it but it seems that the router.navigate doesn't wait for the result of the guard

Comment: @firasKoubaa Can you share the code snippets of the Guards?*

Comment: @Shravan here is it

Comment: @KurtHamilton already updated my question

Comment: @firasKoubaa What type does `this.myService.getPermission()` return?

Comment: it'seems to be a n observable , i update again my question

Comment: @firasKoubaa Can you create a minimal reproducible app in Stackblitz? It looks fine at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `myTreatment()` method is returning an Observable, you should be returning that Observable again in `getPermissions()` method rather than subscribing on it.

Modify your method as shown below:

```
  public getPermission() {
    /**
     * If myTreatment() method returns an Observable of boolean type
     * remove the pipe() method altogether.
    */

    return myTreatment().pipe(
      map(res => {
        let result = false;
        // Perform your logic and assign a boolean value to the variable
        return result;
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guard should be:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.myService.getPermission();
  }

  canActivateChild(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.canActivate(next, state);
  }

}
```

Service should contain:

```
public getPermission(): Observable<boolean> {
    return myTreatment();
}
```